# Fetch MP3 ID3 tag under linux

Tags: linux, mp3, tags, id3, winamp

I have a few mp3 files which are not tagged. Winamp has a nice feature which I think is called "autotag" and which is very good at finding out artist and title for files. I'd like something like this for unix, so that I could possibly get artists and titles for my untagged files. Do you know some program which does this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardTagger)

Answer (score 0):

[Amarok](http://amarok.kde.org/) has some great tagging features, including interaction with [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/).